pd dataframe applymap tries to modify col names
Hello  i have a dataframe containing datetime infos and i'd like too format those infos so i've used this command  :
df2[["month", "day", "hour", "min", "s"]] = df2[["month", "day", "hour", "min", "s"]].applymap(lambda x: f"{int(x):02d}")

However i get this error : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'month'
so my guess is the applymap function is trying to apply the format on column name, how would you solve this problem ?
here is a sample of the data :

so i'd like month values to be '01' instead of '1'

Can you add sample of data to question?

It should mean that one of your selected columns contains the value "month". Whether that is true or not, you can check easily enough. Otherwise, without any data, that is no way for SO users to reproduce this. Share a [mre]. Don't post pictures of your data, share a sample as text. E.g., df.head(10).to_dict().

yeah that was my first thought too but no 'month' value inside 'month' column

Again, you need to show a sample that reproduces the issue. Otherwise, we are all just guessing here. And it need not be column 'month', it could be any of the columns you selected.

Can you test if non numeric values in month values by print (df2[pd.to_numeric(df2["month"], errors='coerce').isna()]) ?

@jezrael i've downloaded the dataframe exported in csv, filtered values on column 'month' and every values are numeric (0,7 or 1)

i used :
df2[["month", "day", "hour", "min", "s"]].applymap(lambda x: f"{int(x):02d}")

instead of :
df2[["month", "day", "hour", "min", "s"]] = df2[["month", "day", "hour", "min", "s"]].applymap(lambda x: f"{int(x):02d}")

and it works now don't understand why
